# How to put projects in one folder in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I did some problem-solving in C++, and the current file structure looks like this.

```
solution_folder/
├── question_1/
│   ├── Main.cpp
│   ├── question_1.vcxproj
│   └── question_1.vcxproj.filters
├── question_2/...
├── (more project folders)
└── solution.sln
```

I want to put all projects in one folder and still be able to open the solution in Visual Studio just as I used to before. I don't want to scroll through hundreds of folders to get to the readme section when I upload the solution on GitHub.

```
solution_folder/
├── src/
│   ├── question_1/
│   │   ├── Main.cpp
│   │   ├── question_1.vcxproj
│   │   └── question_1.vcxproj.filters
│   ├── question_2/...
│   └── (more project folders)
└── solution.sln
```

Is this possible? Should I not create a project for each question?

Comment: Yes it is possible to make just about any folder layout you want.

Comment: @drescherjm If I create a folder and move the project folders in it, neither the newly created folder nor the project folders are no longer visible in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: I think you can use add existing project to add the project to your solution in the new location. For the last 13 years I use CMake to generate my Visual Studio projects so I don't do this anymore however I do have my projects organized by a much more complicated hierarchy of folders.

Comment: I you have already re-origanized your projects into different folder structure, then in Visual Studio, right-click on every existing project in the solution and click _Remove_. Now, right-click on the **solution** and click _Add_, then click _Existing Project_, and select a project from the correct (new) location. Repeat this (adding an existing project) for all the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@drescherjm* and *@heapunderrun* commented,

1. Put all project folders in one folder in File Explorer,
2. **Remove** all projects from the solution in Solution Explorer,
3. Right-click on the solution and **Add → Existing Project** all projects.

---

**Update:**

Shortcuts

- Remove: `Delete`
- Add existing project: `Alt F D E`